# Submit a parameter via form_for that isn't an attribute on the model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relatively simple question. I have a `form_for` which works nicely, I'd like to pass through a random parameter that doesn't belong to the User model, nor to any associated model (e.g. it shouldn't rely on `accepts_nested_attributes_for`).

When I try to add it to the form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

<h2>Sign up</h2
  
  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

  <%= f.label :foo %>
  <%= f.text_field :foo %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
<% end %>
```

The view is loaded with this error:

```
undefined method `foo' for #<User id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, admin: nil, last_seen_at: nil, time_zone: nil, phone: nil, temp_role: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, email: "">
```

I understand why the error is happening; because there's no foo attribute on the User model.

But I'd still like to pass the `foo` variable through to the controller. What's the best way of doing that (assuming there *is* a way)?

Comment: But if you want to pass the `foo` attribute to user model you can set `attr_accessor :foo` in user model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it without editing the model and that may be handy if this parameter is not really a part of the model.

You can just add plain tags inside the `form_for` like this:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

<h2>Sign up</h2
  
  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

  <%= label_tag :foo %>
  <%= text_field_tag :foo %>

  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
<% end %>
```

In this case parameter `foo` will be outside of `user` hash, so `params` will be like

```
{"user"=> ["first_name"=> "Bob"], "foo"=>"bar"...}
```